# Software to simulate mechanics of production line

Tags: simulation, hardware, cad, modeling

Is there any software where I can simulate production line elements (joints, motors, springs, actuators, movement)? For example I want to simulate mechanism to unwind paper from big roll to weld it later with bubble foil and finally make bubble foil envelope, mechanism will look like this: [image: mechanism].

I need it as simple as possible and preferably free. Can be any OS.

(So far I thought about Blender and FreeCAD)